# Изменение html при отправке запроса через WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, html

Привет.

У меня есть WebSoket чат, и нужно осуществить такую задачу. При отправке моего сообщения на сервер Div class должен принимать значение mymessage, иначе message. Как можно реализовать эту задачу на JS? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Лёва Черненко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

У каждого сообщения есть свой id. В том месте, где генерируется список сообщений, надо каждому div-элементу присвоить id = id_message.
Затем по отправке сообщения генерируется новое сообщение с новым id.
Этот id передаешь в функцию JavaScript,  которой будет вот такой код по смене класса:

```
$('#id_message').attr('class', 'mymessage');
```

А в иделае вместо attr лучше использовать `.removeClass` и `.addClass`.

*П.С. Я бы отправку сообщения реализовал асинхронным-ajax, который в ответ вернет нам json, который будет содержать id сообщения. И после чего ты меняешь класс на mymessage.*

Comment: Сокет сервер не отправляет никаких id сообщений, голый текст.

Comment: Дай url, на котором установлен этот чат. А я посмотрю уже код и тогда смогу что нить тебе ответить

Answer (score 2):

**я до конца не понял, отправляемые и полученные данные?!**

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://site');
//при получении
ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    $('.class_div').html(e.data);
};
//при отправки
WSSend = function(msg,ws) {
    ws.send(msg);
    $('.class_div').html(msg);
}
WSSend('тра-ля-ля',ws);
```